# Given an array A size of n of real numbers. It consists of n/logn sorted sequences

Tags: time-complexity, lower-bound

> Given an array A size of n of real numbers. It consists of n/logn sorted
> sequences (each sequence of size logn).
>
> Prove that it's not possible to sort the array A in time complexity of
> o(nlogn) (Small o nation) in worst case.
>
> Make an assumption that its possible then to contradict it with lower
> bound theorem.

I need help in just understanding the question. As what I have concluded that they are asking to prove that we can't get any sorting algorithm less than O(nlogn)?

Comment: Under the assumption that this array consists n/logn sorted sequences, you need to prove that it is not possible to sort the whole array in a better time than nlogn.

Comment: @e.ad Could I prove it by using a specific sorting algorithm (merge, heap) and shows its not better than nlogn?

Comment: As far as I know this type of questions there two main ways to prove this: 1. (as hinted in the question in your post) assume that you have a b 'black box' algorithm that sort this type of arrays in o(nlogn) and then show that with that black box algorithm you can sort ANY array in o(nlogn) and this is a contradiction

Comment: the second way is to show that even in this type of array there are O(n * 2^n) possible outputs. (this is also implies that there is no algorithm that can sort that array in under nlogn)

Comment: tell me if you got the idea